# pdf editing via html

Tags: android, pdf, annotations, itext, ocr

Not sure if this is the right place for this question but i wasn't able to find any other medium of advise.

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you don't consider attempting text extraction from the PDF before OCR'ing?

Comment: That is the reason for making the user select.  It does not explain, though, why you do not want to go for text extraction from the marked area before OCR'ing it.

Comment: PDF is a format which can already contain the information which text is present somewhere on the PDF page. If your PDFs contain that information, OCR is not required and, therefore, you won't get the OCR errors. But as mentioned in my first comment, this is but an aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text extraction.  As mkl mentioned in comments, PDF may already contain a layer of text (digitally created or pre-OCRed), or it may be image-only PDF without text (scanned or rasterized).  Existing text extraction can be attempted, but I give it low chance of success because PDF does not have coordinate information for text extraction purposes.  In other words, it is very easy to programatically extract ALL existing text from within a PDF, but it is hard to extract text from a specific zone or region.  For this reason, OCR is frequently used even if text already exists inside, because OCR returns text with very detailed location and region information, which can be mapped to the image coordinates.

PDF zone highlighting.  I believe you will either have to re-build a new PDF with certain area highlighted, or build your own PDF-like viewer that will merry image and coordinates and text and highlighted area.  I would go for the second option of creating your own viewer because you have extra controls over functionality and UI.  Your viewer could take PDF as input and produce modified PDF as output, but as you work with the document it does not have to be a PDF, even though it could behave like PDF to the user's perspective, but with added functionality for interaction.